# Using ng-repeat on deep nest json

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm playing around with Angular for the first time and having trouble with ng-repeat, repeating thought a json

```
            [
                {
                    "class": "Torture",
                    "type": "Cruiser",
                    "name": "The Impending Doom",
                    "leadership": 7,
                    "pts": "250 pts",
                    "speed": "35cm",
                    "turns": "90\u00B0",
                    "armour": 5,
                    "squadron": "Death Makes",
                    "hitpoints": 6,
                    "weapons": [
                        {
                            "name": "Impaler",
                            "firepower": 2,
                            "ordnances": [
                                { 
                                    "type": "Attack Craft",
                                    "range": "30cm"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "refits": {},
                    "crew skills": {},
                    "battle log": [
                        {
                            "Data": "",
                            "Log": ""
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "class": "Torture",
                    "type": "Cruiser",
                    "name": "Pain Giver",
                    "leadership": 7,
                    "pts": "250 pts",
                    "speed": "35cm",
                    "turns": "90\u00B0",
                    "armour": 5,
                    "squadron": "Death Makes",
                    "hitpoints": 6,
                    "weapons": [
                        {
                            "name": "Launch Bays",
                            "firepower": 4,
                            "ordnances": [
                                { 
                                    "type":"Fighters",
                                    "range": "30cm" 
                                },
                                { 
                                    "type":"Bombers",
                                    "range": "20cm" 
                                },
                                { 
                                    "type":"Boats",
                                    "range": "30cm" 
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Prow Torpedo Tubes",
                            "firepower": 4,
                            "ordnances": [
                                {   
                                    "type": "Torpedos",
                                    "range": "30cm" 
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "refits": {},
                    "crew skills": {},
                    "battle log": [
                        {
                            "Data": "",
                            "Log": ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Now the problem I have is when I try to repeat thought the ordnance's I get the worry amount as there a two different amount of ordnance's.

Here my HTML

```
                    <div ng-repeat="ship in fleet" class="squadron__table">
                    <table>
                        <caption>{{ ship.name }}</caption>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="space">{{ ship.type }}</td>
                                <td class="space">{{ ship.class }}</td>
                                <td class="space">{{ ship.leadership }}</td>
                                <td class="space">{{ ship.speed }}</td>
                                <td class="space">{{ ship.turns }}</td>
                                <td class="space">{{ ship.armour }}</td>
                                <td class="space">{{ ship.hitpoints }}</td>
                                <td class="space">{{ ship.pts }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="2">Armament</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Fire power</th>
                                <th colspan="4">Ordnance</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="weapon in ship.weapons">
                                <td colspan="2">{{ weapon.name }}</td>
                                <td colspan="2">{{ weapon.firepower }}</td>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                            {{ weapon.ordnances.type }}
                                            ---
                                            {{  weapon.ordnances.range }}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
                 </div>
```

and the controller

```
$http.get( '/json/' + $routeParams.squadrionName + '.json', { cache: $templateCache } )
  .success(function( data) {
    $scope.fleet = data;
  })
```

The end result I'm looking for is 
when the ship has launch bays and torpedo it print s out the three different type of ship and the one torpedos.

Comment: The sample data is a bit too big. For help reducing it to a palatable size, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ordnances can have one or more than one items so you need to use the ngRepeat again, like this:

```
<td colspan="4">
  <div ng-repeat="ordnance in weapon.ordnances">
    {{ ordnance.type }} --- {{ ordnance.range }}
  </div>
</td
```